# Metric tensor's relation to gravitation potential

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, potential-energy

I am trying to figure out the role of gravitation potential and its generalization to the metric tensor.

I know how we can relate the gravitation potential and the metric by looking at the geodesic equation and using some weak field, low speeds approximations along with the equation $a = -\text{grad} \,\,\phi$, we can get the coefficent of $dt$ as $\left(1+\frac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)$.

What I want to do is derive this relation in a more intuitive way. What I tried to do is look at a free-falling particle in a uniform gravitation field at a certain point. Then in a frame in its instantaneous velocity, the particle travels $d\tau$ in time and approximately $-\frac{1}{2}g \, d\tau^2$ in space. Then we can use Lorentz transformation under the instantaneous velocity to calculate $dt$ and $dx$ in the stationary frame. From here I am stuck because I think the Lorentz transformation used needs to have some second-order terms in order to result in the coefficient $\left(1+\frac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)$.

Alternatively, is there a direct way to get that coefficient from Rindler coordinates?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

why not just assume the metric:

$$ds^{2} = -\left(c^{2} + 2\phi\right)dt^{2} + d^{3}x$$

, and then work out the geodesic equations, and show that they have the properties you want, rather than try to derive it the other way around?

Comment: Because then it would seem this equation came out of nowhere. Also this is a more of a mathematical derivation rather than a physical derivation. I would prefer the latter over the former wherever it is possible, even though my background is in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I would consider a more intuitive solution, which is a slightly modified version of the red shift argument. Basically when in a falling elevator, starting from rest, a light signal is emitted from the top of the elevator x' = 0 to the bottom in time $d\tau$ and the length of the elevator is $dx'=cd\tau$. So $ds^2 = c^2d\tau^2 - dx'^2 = 0$.

When looking at it from outside the elevator, the light signal is emitted from $x=0$ and reaches the bottom which is $dx'+\frac{1}{2}gdt^2$ away using kinematics in the frame at $x=0$. The problem is that since the lift is accelerating, every $x$ is a different frame and we need to look at the frame at $x=dx'+\frac{1}{2}gdt^2$.

What we can reason is that given light is wave, the number of periods $N$ this light signal goes through from the top to bottom would be preserved in both frames. Inside the falling elevator, $N \lambda_0 = dx'$. Outside, the light frequency and wavelength changes at each $x$ between $0$ and $dx'+\frac{1}{2}gdt^2$, but as the distance is infinitesimally small, we can approximate the change in wavelength linearly with respect to the period travelled by the light wave, i.e., $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \alpha n$, $n$ being the period travelled by the light signal. Integrating with respect to period will give the total distance travelled, which we have already calculated before to be $dx'+\frac{1}{2}gdt^2$.

So $\int^N_0\lambda dn = N\lambda_0 + \alpha \frac{N^2}{2} = dx'+\frac{1}{2}gdt^2$. Solving this equation gives $\alpha = \frac{gdt^2}{N^2}$ and we can then calculate the wavelength at the bottom of the lift to be $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \frac{gdt^2\lambda_0}{dx'}$. Using the fact that the instantaneous frame at the point of the light signal emitting, the velocity between inside and outside of the elevator is $0$, we can use $dt$ and $d\tau$ interchangeably and $\frac{dx'}{dt} = c$. This equation becomes $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_0} = 1+\frac{gdx'}{c^2}$, which is the time conversion factor from the time at bottom of elevator to top of elevator. This shows time on top of elevator is more than the bottom (gravitational time dilation). It also means that while at the top of the lift $c^2dt^2-dx^2=0$, using $(t_b,x_b)$ to denote the spacetime coordinates at the bottom of the elevator, the equation becomes $c^2(1+\frac{gdx'}{c^2})^2dt_b^2 - dx_b^2 = 0$.

And since we've been using low velocity assumption, the equation becomes $c^2(1+\frac{2gdx'}{c^2})dt_b^2 - dx_b^2 = 0$.